# Error while opening network in Nautilus

Tags: 11.04, networking, nautilus

What does this mean

> Error: DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive
>   a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send
>   a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply
>   timeout expired, or the network connection was broken. Please select
>   another viewer and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to establish an FTP connection and the problem disappeared for no reason.

But check your internet connection, whether you've typed the URL correctly etc.

Comment: i am trying to access files from a win 7 system over the same network